# WPF CanExecute and ThreadPool

Tags: wpf, threadpool, canexecute

My application executes a webservice call and when it happens, the IsExecuting status is set to true and the execute button is disabled. Because the application is not responsive during this period i change the process so the execution is happening in a seperate thread. However the problem that i'm noticing now is, the execute button is still disabled and only when i clicked on the Interface the button gets enabled. How can i fix this?

EDIT:
    In Codebehind:

```
private void Execute()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExecuteThread));
}

private bool CanExecute
{
    get  { return !IsExecuting; }
}

private void ExecuteThread(Object o)
{
    IsExecuting = true;

    // Process execution here ...

    IsExecuting = false;
}


In Xaml:

<Button Content="Execute" Command="{Binding Path=ExecCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to refresh the `CanExecute` status of your commands? Just call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`, this will cause `CanExecute` to be reevaluated on bound commands.

Comment: I've tried this by adding it as the last line in ExecuteThread Method, however it didn't help.

Comment: @Sys, try to call this method on the UI thread (using Dispatcher.Current.Invoke)

Comment: I've tried Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { IsExecuting = true; })); but again not working...

Comment: You can assign the property on any thread, it doesn't matter. What I told you to try is to call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() on the UI thraed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post some code to better understand your problem.

I'm quite sure it is a thread issue as you can't change the status of a control's form from a different Thread.

I think all you need to to is use a Delegate to update the status of your button from other thread

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)